# RAD Studio - C++ Builder 11.3 / Delphi - Design View - Change form size without moving controls that are anchored?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

Sometimes I need to adjust the Dialog size to add more controls.  Is there a built-in way to resize it so the anchored controls don't move as well.  Something like hold some shift, ctrl or shift-ctrl, etc.. while moving?  Instead of having to disable the right or bottom anchor for all the controls then enabling them again.

TIA!!

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. A cheap and dirty workaround would be to put all of the components onto a client-aligned container like TPanel, that way you only have to deactivate the anchors on just the Panel. Or, you could select every component on the Form, then Cut them to the clipboard, then resize the Form, then paste the clipboard back onto the Form.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to not use design view. Right click the form and **View as Text** or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> to toggle between form and text view and modify dimensions there. Changing the form dimensions in text view does not update the position of anchored controls.